# Pass private proxy credentials in Webclient

Tags: c#, proxy, httpclient, web-crawler, webclient

I have a C# Winforms application in vs 2012. There is a web client function in my application. I already purchase a private proxy for this application.

But it needs to get credentials before using the private proxy address. How to pass the credentials to the `webclient` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign "Proxy" property and it's Credentials property:

```
var Client = new WebClient();
Client.Proxy = new WebProxy("31.4.5.26", 8080); // proxy's host,port
Client.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("proxyuser","proxypassword");
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. Do you pass any domain name.
i purchase my proxy in the ProxyBlaze website.

Comment: @Ragesh Puthiyedath , Yes, you can pass domain name of any host to WebProxy's constructor. 

Also there is many other more complicated, but also more "powerfull" constructors for this class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.webproxy(v=vs.110).aspx